# Avoiding exceptions with conditional updates (dynamoDB, Java)

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to update a dynamoDB table conditionally in Java. I have a query that increments an attribute if the condition evaluates to true, but if it fails then the query throws an exception.

Is there a way to avoid this exception and have the query return the old item?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not out of the box, but you can do something like this:

```
try {
    item = table.updateItem(updateItemSpec); 
} catch (ConditionalCheckFailedException ce) {
    item = table.getItem(...)
    ...
}
```